# Bad quality "hollow and distorted" sound on iMac

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, mac

**Background info**:

- Late 2009 iMac
- Ubuntu 17.10
- Using Apple's internal speakers
- No modified settings
- Default sound drivers

**Description**:

Any kind of sound or music in any application sounds distorted and hollow. The sound quality is noticeably different from macOS regardless of the application I use, especially when music is playing. My normal output volume is really low, below unamplified. I also don't allow any louder than 100%.

**Question**:

What can I do to fix this? I've already seen some questions similar to this but none of them actually helped that much.

Comment: Have the same problem with an iMac 2012. The sound quality on macOS Mojave is great but on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS sitting on the same device as a bootable OS, it is significantly worse.

Comment: Did you find any solutions?